# (Angular) Simple nested views not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, pug, livescript, nested-views

I'm studying Angular, and I'm stuck with `ui-router`. 
Here is the code. I'm using PUG & Livescript, I doubt that I'm having issue because of these two.

My codes are similar to some answers here in stackoverflow, but I can't make it to work. `create.pug` is not showing.

main.pug is a child of index.pug 
create.pug is a child of main.pug

create.pug -> main.pug -> index.pug

versions:

```
angular -> 1.6.3
angular-ui-router -> 0.4.2
```

index.pug

```
html(ng-app="app.main")
  head ...
  body
    div(ui-view)
```

main.pug

```
md-subheader
  h1 To Do

md-divider
section(ui-view)
```

create.pug

```
md-input-container
  label Title
  input(type="test" ng-model="app.new_task" ng-keypress="createTask($event)")
```

main.ls

```
MainController = ($scope) !->

angular
  .module 'app.main'
  .controller 'MainController', MainController
```

create.ls

```
TaskCreateController = ($scope) !->
  app = @

  app.taskList = []

  $scope.createTask = ($event) !->
    if $event.keyCode !== 13 || !app.new_task
      return

  app.taskList.push app.new_task
  app.new_task = ''

  angular
    .module 'app.main'
    .controller 'TaskCreateController', TaskCreateController
```

router.ls

```
routeHelper = ($locationProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) !->
this.$get = ($state) ->
  'configureStates': (states) !->
      Object
        .entries states
        .forEach ([name, config]) !->
          $stateProvider.state name, config

$locationProvider.html5Mode false
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise '/'

angular
  .module 'app.main'
  .provider 'routeHelper', routeHelper
```

routes.ls

```
setupRoutes = (routeHelper) !->
  routeHelper.configureStates do
    'home':
      'url': '/'
      'templateUrl': 'modules/main/main.html'
      'controller': 'MainController'
      'controllerAs': 'app'

    'home.create':
      'url': '/create'
      'templateUrl': 'modules/task/create/create.html'
      'controller': 'TaskCreateController'
      'controllerAs': 'app'

angular
  .module 'app.main'
  .run setupRoutes
```

Comment: What is not working ?

Comment: create.pug is not showing

Comment: ok then IMO it's necessary to see how you do template inheritance, to have the full picture.

Comment: these are the only files that I have (excluding vendor files, for now)
I'm not sure what exactly is template inheritance, I'm new to this.

Comment: When you say "main.pug is a child of index.pug ", how do you make that, do you use Pug [includes](https://pugjs.org/language/includes.html) or [content bloks](https://pugjs.org/language/inheritance.html) ?

Comment: I use this inside of index.pug `div(ui-view)`.
Is this not enough? some of the blogs and tutorial only use `ui-view`.

Comment: `ui-view` looks nice. But it has to be seen from the `ng-app`. On `index.pug` that looks fine. But in your other pug files, I doubt it. Without template inheritance, main.pug has no way to be below the `ng-app`. I'd check that in your final html, ng-app is in a tag that embrasses the rest of the html. How you showed us in the question looks like you have different html files that are not linked together. So the JS app that is started in one can not see the html of the others.

Comment: I'd advise to start smaller. Start with a file, check the ng app works, add another pug file and check. It's complicated and confusing now.

Answer (score 0):

mmh I'd try to add an indentation level here:

```
head(ng-app="app.main") ...
body
  div(ui-view)
```

to

```
head(ng-app="app.main") ...
  body
    div(ui-view)
```

or rather

```
html(ng-app="app.main")
  head
  body
```

Comment: Sorry my mistake, my `ng-app` is in the html.
I'll edit my question.